# How to Stop increasing the size of textbox when another textbox increase its size on report

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I am working with Access Report and I have multiple fields in report.

[image: Access report view]

3 of the field (Textbox) is Richtext (Memo field). It handles more than 255 characaters. if the textbox data increase it also increase the hight of the textbox. This behaviour is desireable and it works.

One of field contain the conditional formatting which makes the backcolor 'orange' or 'Red' based on condition. [image: Check immage]

The Problem it also increase the height of the textbox same as other field.

How can I disable the increasing of the height for that particular textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove the field from the stacked Layout and now It is not increasing its size.

post anyother suggestion if its possible without removing the layout.

Comment: That would have been my suggestion too. :)