# Microsoft Access Report With a Cell that "can grow"

Tags: ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access report that has one cell that "can Grow" vertically.
In the output, when that cell does grow, the other cells in that line stay at the default hight, even if I set them to "can grow". The final report becomes very ugly when I have the cell's borders showing. Is there a way to work around this, meaning, a way to make all cells to grow with the one that does need to grow?

I did try looking in the forums and google and couldn't find good words to explain my problem in a small search text, didn't find anything about this.

Ty for any help you can give me.

Comment: arrange all textbox in stacked layout so that when any one cell / textbox grows it will automatically grows all other cells.

Comment: if you want any other cell / textbox to not increase is size than remove only that component from stacked layout. I had that kind of problem before. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741840/how-to-stop-increasing-the-size-of-textbox-when-another-textbox-increase-its-siz)

Comment: @Tarun.P, sounds like a valid answer if you want to write it up. Alternative to grouped layout is VBA in OnFormat event to set height of controls to match.

Comment: @Tarun. P Ty that's real close to what i was looking for. However I got a border problem now, if i set left and right border it draws 2 lines if i only set left its allmost perfect but the last column doesnt show. How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: @JoãoHorta the settings of border has nothing to do with last column. if it doesn't show than it can be a different problem. share some more info with screenshot.